# How make a reference between .NET Core Libraries?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dll

i´m new in .NET Core and make my first steps.

I created two **.NET Core 3.1** Libraries with the Name *ScanDirectory.Contract.dll* and *ScanIOItems.Contract.dll*. The *ScanDirectory.Contract.dll* need the Objects from the *ScanIOItems.Contract.dll* (simple POCO classes as public). In normal case (classic .NET Framework) i make a reference in Visual Studio.
In .NET Core it doesn´t work. How can i get access to the ScanDirectory.Contract.dll classes? How make a reference between .NET Core Libraries?

regards

Comment: What behavior do you experience? It should work the same as .NET Framework libraries.

Comment: are you using visual studio?

Comment: @  vivek nunaYes, i use VS 2019.

Comment: @  vivek nuna: Yes, i use VS 2019. @ Crowcoder: It doesn´t work. This is the reason why i so confused. Normal .NET Framwork libraries works fine. References etc., no problem. But when i create the same Classes in a new Library (.Net Core 3.1), i can´t get a reference between two .Net Core Libs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I reinstalled .Net Core and now it works. I have no clue why but it works :-)

thx for your help.

regards